# Use of "the" in front of an application name

Tags: definite-articles, proper-nouns

I am currently writing my thesis. It is based upon an application that I developed. 
My question is that should I use *the* in front of my application's name in my thesis.

In this example suppose my app's name is *mSecure*:

> Applying the concepts of HCI in the development of *mSecure*.

OR

> Applying the concepts of HCI in the development of the *mSecure*. (This sounds weird to me)

Also, later on if I have a sentence like this:

> The user of the *mSecure* must be healthy.

OR

> The user of *mSecure* must be healthy.

Can some one please point out which of the above sentences are more appropriate?

Comment: Suggested migration to [ell.se]

Comment: Usage of _"the"_ is suggested only when you use a word like _app_ with mSecure, ex- _"Applying the concepts of HCI in development of the mSecure app"_. However, go without the _"the"_.

Comment: @LasciviousGrace Other mistake that I made is using `the` in front of development? So would this be correct "Applying HCI concepts in development of mSecure."

Comment: The definite article _"the"_ should be used depending on your sentence construction. For instance- in the sentence in my example- _"Applying the concepts of HCI in development of the mSecure app"_: here you have _"the"_ before _concepts_ and before _mSecure_, so you can probably skip using _the_ before _development_. But in the sentence in your comment above, you need a _the_ before development. 

Lookup the usage of definite article here: http://www.writing.utoronto.ca/advice/english-as-a-second-language/definite-article and https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use "the" with your application name.  In this case the application name functions in the same way as the name of a person (or dog, or other animal I suppose) and it would be unusual (and highly stylistic) to place a "the" in front of the name.